# Get-WmiObject -query return nothing/null

Tags: powershell

I'm running this in powershell

```
PS C:\>Get-WmiObject -query "select * from  Win32_OptionalFeature where name = 'RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles-AD-Powershell'"
```

On my Windows 7 machine I'm getting correct output

```
__GENUS          : 2
__CLASS          : Win32_OptionalFeature
__SUPERCLASS     : CIM_LogicalElement
__DYNASTY        : CIM_ManagedSystemElement
__RELPATH        : Win32_OptionalFeature.Name="RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles-AD-Powershell"
__PROPERTY_COUNT : 6
__DERIVATION     : {CIM_LogicalElement, CIM_ManagedSystemElement}
__SERVER         : TTL001343
__NAMESPACE      : root\cimv2
__PATH           : \\TTL001343\root\cimv2:Win32_OptionalFeature.Name="RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles-AD-Powershell"
Caption          : Active Directory Module for Windows PowerShell
Description      :
InstallDate      :
InstallState     : 2
Name             : RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles-AD-Powershell
Status           :
```

But when I run this same command on Windows 2008 Server box in virtual environment, I get empty out put. Any idea why?

Note: in both machines I'm running powershell in Admin mode.

Comment: is RemoteServerAdministrationTools enabled on the Windows 2008 box?

Comment: Yes I can see it enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting crazy for a day. I found I should be using this command for Windows 2008 Server.

```
PS C:\>import-module servermanager
PS C:\>$feature=get-windowsfeature RSAT-AD-PowerShell
```

Now I can use it like this

```
PS C:\> $feature.Installed
True
```

**Helpful links:**

**Windows 2008**
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee662309.aspx

**Windows 2012**
http://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj205467(v=wps.620).aspx

Answer (score 3):

I would run this:

```
gwmi Win32_OptionalFeature | sort-object -Property Name | select-object Name
```

And see if the feature in question is there with a slightly different name.

As was noted in the comment, RSAT might not be enabled at all, which would impact what you're seeing

Comment: I was looking for RemoteServerAdministrationTools-Roles-AD-Powershell, but couldn't find something close to it.